# Converting UTC time in IST

Tags: java, android

I have to convert `2017-10-12T09:48:28.338Z` to IST i.e `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` . The code i used throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'`

Here is my code :

```
private String getStandardTime(String dateStr) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dddd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = df.format(date);
        return formattedDate;
    }
```

Can anyone help me out here ? What i am doing wrong .
for reference i checked

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number

Comment: You really has a date qith 4 Digits as day?

Comment: What is the char `Z` in your date:? `2017-10-12T09:48:28.338Z`?

Comment: You know `SimpleDateFormat` is not a thread safe class ?

Comment: I can not reproduce this error if i run your code by my own.

Comment: @Deepak Rathore do you want to change format or change timezone?

Comment: Hi all . @jens  It was two digit . Imran Ahmad works for me , i had to write z as 'z' .

Comment: @DeepakRathore *It was two Digit*  and why you write 4 placeholders in the pattern?

Comment: @jens it was some typo mistake . But Problem was also in time zone character . Please have a look at Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below line in your code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Z represent Timezone character, you have to quote it like 'Z'. Also you are using dddd instead of dd.

Comment: Your answer helped me . Thanks a ton .

Comment: welcome @DeepakRathore and thanks for accepting the answer.